# Logic Apps and Configuring Office 365 Email

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

Configuring a new service connection to Office 365 from the "Send email via Office 365 Outlook" connector in Logic Apps is failing on Save with the following error -

> Failing to save logic app . The client  has
> permission to perform action 'Microsoft/.Logic/workflows/write' on
> scope , however, it does not have permission
> to perform action 'join/action' on the linked scope
> '/providers/microsoft.web/connections/office365'.

If I am asking for the permissions for the second part what role is that? It seems to be something in Office 365.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Just added the comment. I fixed it with least privilege possibility by applying "Logic Apps Contributor" at the API Connection level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using the Office 365 connecter in the logic app(login your user account to auth successfully), it will create a `office365` API connection (i.e. `microsoft.web/connections/office365` mentioned in the error) in your resource group.

[image]

So to solve the issue, you also need permission at **resource group/subscription** level, not only at logic app level, just navigate to the **resource group/subscription** which the logic app located -> `Access control (IAM)` -> add an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor` like below.

[image]

**Update:**

For the specific error in your question, the least permission is `Microsoft.Web/connections/Join/Action` with no doubt, but if you want to do your stuff successfully, the permission I recommend is `Microsoft.Web/connections/*`, it is small enough, it includes the permissions below, [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftweb).

[image]

Of course, you can only use `Microsoft.Web/connections/Join/Action`, but it may raise another permission error, then you need to fix it again, all depend on your requirements.

To create the custom role, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal), in the [step 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal#step-6-json), use the json like below.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "LogicAPIConnRole",
        "description": "test",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/subscriptions/xxxxx"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.Web/connections/*"
                ],
                "notActions": [],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After the creation, assign the role at the `office365` API connection scope, it will work fine.

Comment: That gives too many permissions. I ended up doing a very similar activity, within the API connections of the Logic Apps and I gave "Logic Apps Contributor" only.

Comment: @NitinRastogi Well, you didn’t say you want the least privilege in your question, Contributor is just a normal role we use more often, if you want the least privilege, Logic Apps Contributor is also not the choice, you need to create a custom RBAC role only includes join/action permission mentioned in the error message, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

Comment: Joy, could you please update the answer to include simplistic permissions, and I will mark it as an answer. Also, I couldn't find the exact RBAC permission I should have picked for the custom RBAC. I wanted to assign that but left it as minimal as I could.