# Error on calling ADF using Logic app : does not have permission to perform action 'join/action' on the linked scope(s)

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, apiconnect

We are calling ADF pipeline from one of our logic app and some issue occurring while established the ADF connection. Below is the error:
**The client 'xxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxx' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows/write' on scope '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/xxxxxx'; however, it does not have permission to perform action 'join/action' on the linked scope(s) '/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuredatafactory-1' or the linked scope(s) are invalid.**

we are having Data factory contributor role, Contributor role on the resource group level. Can someone suggest on the error

Comment: you should try applying "Logic Apps Contributor" privilege at the API Connection level. See if these help, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67438267/15969417) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42134892/15969417)

Comment: Hi Karthik, thanks for your suggestion. I have missed to add, so what we do is we are using logic workflow code as a json file and  we are trying to deploy in Devops through yaml and the error comes in devops.    
                                  
Do you have any suggestion for this?