# Getting below authentication error while connecting outlook.com /360 through the logic apps already have the contributor access

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-logic-apps

> Failed to create connection for connection id '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/outlook'.
>
> The client 'xxx@xxx.xxx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/connections/write'over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/outlook' or the scope is invalid.
>
> If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Trying to connect the Outlook through the logic apps, for the mail trigger when the job failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using  Office 365 connecter in the logic app in your resource group and logged in
Make sure to add Logic App Contributor/ contributor permission at resource group or subscription level.
Check if the role is assigned at only logic app level.
And assign it to larger scope

Accesscontrol(IAM)> **`+Add`**

[image]

Add role assignment> Select Contrubutor from Privileged permissions.
and later also select Logic app contributor if needed.

[image]
and select the resource to assigned> logic app and the user .

[image]
Also check the following

References:

1. [Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#logic-app-contributor)
2. [logic-apps-and-configuring-office-365-email | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67438267/logic-apps-and-configuring-office-365-email)